# NullPointerException initializing variable with string length

Tags: java, recursion, initialization

We were told to implement a method to detect if a string is a palindrome with iteration and recursion. I was successful in implementing the method with iteration but I am getting this error when I try and do it recursively.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at recursion.RecursivePallindrome.isPallindrome(RecursivePallindrome.java:14)
at recursion.RecursivePallindrome.main(RecursivePallindrome.java:44)
```

I'm currently clueless on what has gone wrong.

```
package recursion;

public class RecursivePalindrome {

static String word;
public RecursivePalindrome(String a)
{
    a = word;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome()
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = word.length()-1; //Line 14
        char a = word.charAt(start);
        char z = word.charAt(end);
            Character.toLowerCase(a); Character.toLowerCase(z);

    if(start >= end)
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(a) && Character.isLetter(z))
        {
            if(a == z)
            {
                a++;
                z--;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if(!Character.isLetter(a))
            start++;
        else if(!Character.isLetter(z))
            end--;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new RecursivePalindrome("testing");
    if(isPalindrome())
        System.out.println("Is!");
    else
        System.out.println("Is not!");
}
}
```

Comment: Please either remove all the "static" modifiers except for the one in 'public static void main' - it is bad style to begin with in OOP -, or drop the instantiation and the constructor, and make everything truly static, such that the line 'if(isPalindrome())' becomes 'if(isPalindrome("testing"))'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public RecursivePalindrome(String a) {
    word = a;
}
```

This code works, but **it isn't a recursion!**

```
package recursion;

public class RecursivePalindrome {

    static String word;

    public RecursivePalindrome(String a) {
        word = a;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome() {
        int start = 0;
        int end = word.length() - 1;
        char a = word.charAt(start);
        char z = word.charAt(end);
        Character.toLowerCase(a);
        Character.toLowerCase(z);

        while (start < end) {
            if (Character.isLetter(a) && Character.isLetter(z)) {
                if (a == z) {
                    start++;
                    end--;
                    a = word.charAt(start);
                    z = word.charAt(end);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!Character.isLetter(a)) {
                start++;
            } else if (!Character.isLetter(z)) {
                end--;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RecursivePalindrome("testing");
        if (isPalindrome())
            System.out.println("Is!");
        else
            System.out.println("Is not!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Published true recursive solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253981/recursive-solution-to-check-if-string-is-a-palindrome-java/23253982#23253982

Answer (score 0):

Here's a case of me not taking my time. In the constructor I got my assignment mixed up.

```
public RecursivePalindrome(String a)
{
a = word;
}
```

with the proper code being

```
public RecursivePalindrome(String a)
{
word = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `word`.
You may want to change

```
a = word;
```

to

```
word = a;
```